# EntityFramework - Core project vs. Web project with shared entities?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I'm having troubles getting this right...

I have a "Core" project with a common set of functionality including for instance *Tagging*. Tagging includes a set of entities some of which include `Tag` and `ObjectTag`.

They basically look like this:

```
Tag       (uniqueidentifier TagId, nvarchar(max) Tag)
ObjectTag (uniqueidentifier TagId, uniqueidentifier ObjectId)
```

My "Core" project also contains a data model with `DbContext` called `CoreEntities`. So I can do the following:

```
from ot in CoreEntities.Tag select ot where ot.TagId = "{someguid}"
```

I also have a "Web" project which includes object specific to my website for instance *Recipe*. Recipe looks like this:

```
Recipe    (uniqueidentifier RecipeId, string Name)
```

My "Web" project also has a data model with corresponding context (`WebEntities`) which makes the following possible:

```
var recipes = from r in WebEntities.Recipe 
              select r 
              where r.Name == "Granny's Meatloaf"

foreach(var r in recipes) {
    var recipeTags = from t in CoreEntities.ObjectTag 
                     select t 
                     where t.ObjectId == r.RecipeId
}
```

This is pretty resource intensive as for every `Recipe` the corresponding `ObjectTag` records have to be fetched. When trying to join the entities I got the following error: "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts". **Does this mean I need to add `ObjectTag` to my `WebEntities` context? Might there be some other efficient way on joining the two?**

Comment: Do you really need two separate contexts?

Comment: @veblock: I have two separate assemblies with two different `.edmx` files. Visual studio automatically creates two contexts... I'm not sure if I can re-use the context somehow? I prefer to re-use the context from my "Core" project, however it is not an option to add the "Web" entities to the "Core" `.edmx`. file.

Comment: Well can't think of any easy solution. As long as you have 2 separate contexts, it is gonna be resource intensive. I'd rather try to come up with universal entity model to cater for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not split the related entities into different contexts when using EF. The entity classes may reside in different namespaces(projects, etc..) but they should be part of a single context inorder to define a rich model.

It would be better to create a class library project that will contain all the domain entities. This would allow you to declare navigational properties without inter dependent project modules.

The query would be very simple

```
var recipes = from r in MyEntities.Recipe.Include("Tags") 
              select r 
              where r.Name == "Granny's Meatloaf";
```

Comment: I understand, however the `DbContext` generator creates multiple contexts. I'm not able to put all entities in the same project because the `Web` entities are specific to the `Web` project. The `Tag` entity for instance is generic functionality which is used in multiple projects...

Comment: @ReFocus Still you can map it to `WebEntities`.

Comment: @Erange: I don't see how this would be done? The `WebEntities` context is generated automatically... It contains the `DbSet<Recipe>` while the `CoreEntities` contains a `DbSet<Tag>`. What do you mean by "map it to `WebEntities`" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var recipes = (from r in WebEntities.Recipe 
              select r 
              where r.Name == "Granny's Meatloaf").ToList();
```